# Why does file.delete() or file.deleteOnExit() not delete my file

Tags: java, user-interface, menu, menuitem, menubar

I have defined a MenuBar, a Menu and an Item and a Scanner for the file. I assigned (to the item) this actionlistener:

```
item4.addActionListener(ActionListener -> {
            this.dispose();
            Window window = new Window();
            FS.close();
            file.deleteOnExit();
});
```

I looked up why it wasn't deleting my file and saw that people said it was because a FileWriter or Scanner was still open. However, I have closed the scanner (FS.close()) and it still won't delete my file. I have also tried putting the:

```
FS.close();
file.delete();
```

above the this.dispose and it still won't delete it.

Comment: Try to verify if your instructions are executed.
Check if file.delete returns true or false;
Put a log for every line;
Remember: deleteOnExit() method deletes the file when JVM terminates.

Comment: java.io.File is very old and its I/O methods are not good at reporting errors.  Use [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) instead; for example, `Files.delete(file.toPath());`.  It may not successfully delete to file, but you will get an exception that clearly explains what went wrong.

Comment: Check how you terminate your JVM. _Deletion will be attempted only for normal termination of the virtual machine, as defined by the Java Language Specification._ - from 
 [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--).

Comment: @VGR i put that in and it said: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` What processes would it be used in? I have closed my scanner for that file and there is no filewriter active on it

Comment: @abatti yeah, it returned false. Would this be a result of the error I have put in my first reply, and what could I do

Comment: A good way to make sure your Scanners, InputStreams, OutputStreams, etc., are closed, is to place them in a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), so they’ll be closed automatically when you’re done with them.